# How does client cert authentication work on per directory basis?

Tags: apache, ssl, client-certificates

Based on the documentation Apache allows to request a client cert authentication for one directory and don't request it for another directory.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html#arbitraryclients

How is it possible?

I assumed that first TLS/SSL does a handshake (including client certificate validation) and only after it, HTTP request is sent over secured channel. And this HTTP request contains a URL.

So, it looks like to get a URL (a diretory) you need to do (or skip) client certificate authentication.

So, it's not clear for me, how can Apache check URL first and decide later whether to request a client cert authentication or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It uses SSL/TLS renegotiation: the server sends a [TLS Hello Request message](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.1) to ask the client to trigger a new handshake by sending a new Client Hello message (and this time the server will send a Certificate Request after its Server Hello message).

The Hello Request message could in principle happen at any time during the HTTP exchange. For this particular feature, the server sends it just after receiving the request (therefore knowing which resource was requested), but before sending its response.

Comment: Let me repeat to make sure that I understand it correctly. A server makes initial request without client certificate authentication. A client sends HTTP request inside of secure channel. The server checks URL and decides whether it needs to do client cert authentication. In the case if it needs to it will start a new handshake. And as part of this new handshake it will do client authentication.

Comment: Yes. If you're not convinced, you can try to set up a test env with Wireshark (even without a client cert, you should at least see the server's CertificateRequest). Configure a host with `SSLVerifyClient none` and `SSLVerifyClient optional` in a directory. Follow the [Wireshark SSL](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL) tutorial (forcing a non-DHE cipher suite like `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA` might make the test easier for Wireshark). When trying to access something in that dir, you should see a `Hello Request` coming from the server and a 2nd handshake with a `Certificate Request` this time.

Comment: Thanks @user112358 for spotting this mistake.